# Update error in mysql Query taking data from another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to **update** the **orgaization_id** in location table which is primary key in Organization table.

```
update location set organization_id=org.old_id from organization as org 
where location.old_id=org.old_id;
```

Facing syntax **error** please help..

Comment: update location set organization_id=(select org.old_id from organization as org where location.old_id=org.old_id);

Answer (score 1):

You can use join to perform update from another table

```
update location l
join organization as o
on l.old_id=o.old_id
set l.organization_id=o.old_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

`update location set organization_id=(select old_id from organization where organization.old_id=location.old_id);`